# Decoding failed: Syntax error Mass product create

Tags: magento-1.9

I have got following error but i don't know why this

> Decoding failed: Syntax error

Error generate when mass product create using extesions. its work on local and other server correctly.

My JSON code :

```
{\"color\":[\"106\",\"92\",\"126\",\"127\",\"151\",\"108\",\"74\",\"75\",\"76\",\"164\",\"69\",\"65\",\"159\",\"169\",\"168\",\"160\",\"77\",\"170\",\"143\",\"82\",\"91\",\"83\",\"116\",\"9\",\"81\",\"71\",\"136\",\"121\",\"89\",\"140\",\"94\",\"128\",\"117\",\"112\",\"133\",\"134\",\"156\",\"99\",\"93\",\"158\",\"88\",\"149\",\"152\",\"142\",\"129\",\"113\",\"114\",\"177\",\"98\",\"180\",\"96\",\"178\",\"123\",\"161\",\"95\",\"176\",\"72\",\"162\",\"179\",\"167\",\"8\",\"62\",\"118\",\"165\",\"66\",\"181\",\"150\",\"172\",\"111\",\"101\",\"175\",\"87\",\"86\",\"100\",\"166\",\"122\",\"97\",\"84\",\"171\",\"7\",\"6\",\"10\",\"131\",\"132\",\"73\",\"148\",\"157\",\"163\",\"154\",\"153\",\"138\",\"79\",\"145\",\"70\",\"146\",\"139\",\"155\",\"141\",\"144\",\"125\",\"137\",\"105\",\"107\",\"63\",\"80\",\"109\",\"110\",\"124\",\"103\",\"102\",\"104\",\"90\",\"174\",\"135\",\"115\",\"119\",\"173\",\"85\",\"942\",\"67\",\"68\",\"64\",\"120\",\"78\",\"147\",\"130\"],\"wert\":[\"272\",\"273\"]}
```

Comment: The error comes from `lib\Zend\Json.php::decode()` function. It may be because there is some character(special?) breaking JSON string.

Comment: thanks for reply, how to avoid this. please check updated question.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON string ... https://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change in IndexController.php, line no 113 /app/code/community/WP/GenerateSimpleProducts/controllers

```
$selectedParams = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($data['spgOptions']);
```

with

```
$jsonstring = stripslashes(str_replace('\"', '"', $data['spgOptions']));
$selectedParams = json_decode($jsonstring, true);
```